# Reorder array from mysql query

Tags: php

I have an array returned from MYSQL query with 2 LEFT JOINs.
Question is: "Is there another way for writing the code below?". I got the code but I want a more clear way of it just to understand what happens inthere.

CODE:

```
$result = array();
    while ($resultArr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($booksAndAuthors)) {
        $result[$resultArr['book_id']] ['book_name'] = $resultArr['book_title'];
        $result[$resultArr['book_id']] ['author'][] = $resultArr['author_name'];
        print_r($result);
    }
```

Comment: You probably don't want `print_r` inside the loop. You should print it when the whole loop is done.

Comment: Please post your query. This can probably be solved with a GROUP and GROUP_CONCAT.

Comment: @Tom If he uses `GROUP_CONCAT`, he'll need to use `explode()` in the fetch loop to turn it into an array. His code is better, IMHO.

Comment: @Barmar Depends on how many authors he has per book. If its commonly more than 1, a GROUP_CONCAT will reduce the number of loops.

Comment: what is the problem? Your code looks fine minus the `print_r($result)` part which I assume is for debugging only

Comment: @Tom Yes, it will reduce the loops, but complicate the work he has to do in the loops. And he has to make sure that he uses a delimiter in `GROUP_CONCAT` that can never appear in the `author_name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the extract() function you can make the data in the result into variables. I have put the example below inside a function, so they will be local variables.

```
function getBooksAndAuthors($queryResult)
{
  while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryResult)) 
  {
    extract($data);
    $BooksAndAuthors[$book_id] = array('book_name' => $book_title,
                                       'author'    => $author_name);
  }
  return $BooksAndAuthors;
}
```

This makes the code a lot more readable. You will, of course, have to know which columns there are in your database table. I also left out the extra '[]' for the author.

Comment: This doesn't create an array of authors, it just returns the last author in the group.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I recommend writing it, because I don't think you should depend on automatic creation of intermediate arrays.

```
$result = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($booksAndAuthors) {
    $bookid = $row['book_id'];
    if (!isset($result[$bookid])) {
        # First time we see this book, create a result for it
        $result[$bookid] = array('book_name' => $row['book_title'],
                                 'author' => array());
    }
    # add this author to the result entry for the book
    $result[$bookid]['author'][] = $row['author_name'];
}
```

It's essentially equivalent, but I think it also makes the logic clearer.